# Is this natural English: How was it yesterday?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-choice, conversation

People say:

> how was your weekend?

But do they say:

> how was it yesterday?

Is this the natural way of asking about how their yesterday went?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some measures of time lend themselves more naturally to the "How was your X?" construct than others:

- **How was your week?**
  *might be used on a Friday afternoon, asking someone to recap their work week*
- **How was your summer?**
  *might be used when people have been apart for a summer, e.g. after school vacation*
- **How was your day?**
  *without any more information, I'd assume this was uttered in the evening, referring to today*
- **How was your year?**
  *probably uncommon, but it might be heard in, say, financial circles*

These, however, would probably be less heard in conversation:

- How was your decade?
- How was your yesterday?
- How was your month? (*although this one might be heard in sales*)

As for how to inquire about someone's yesterday, I agree with Tim Romano's comments; those were pretty much the first two wordings that came to my mind.

- **How was your day yesterday?**
- **How did things go yesterday?** (*although this is often used in reference to one particular event from yesterday, such as a job interview, as opposed to the whole day*)

When I Googled `"How was your yesterday"` vs `"How was your day yesterday"`, the latter version – How was your **day** yesterday? – seemed much more common.

Answer (score 3):

`"How was it yesterday?"` is a perfectly valid construct, but would be typically used in relation either to something specific that is previously known between both speakers, or querying the state yesterday of something specific. A couple of examples:

- Two co-workers talking in the break room after a meeting that one of
  them could not attend;
- A doctor checking an injury (as per Maulik V's example).

Like Tim Romano and J.R. said, `"How was your day yesterday?"` would make most sense in terms of general small talk.

As for `"How was your yesterday"` - I would only expect to hear that in a particularly idiomatic way, with stress on the 'your' to emphasise the deflection in subject (e.g. "Enough about my interview, how was *your* yesterday?").